Mongo Query with $and and $or
I want to ges all the documentos that are inside a range of dates, but my query instó retriving all the validar Collections:
To resume
My query receives two date values ​​as a string, one for 'arrival' and the other for 'check-out' with these two dates i need to retrive all documents that are between these two dates.
Ex.
arrival='2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z'
check-out='2024-06-16T06:00:00.000Z'
with these values i should retrive all documents in which the 'arrival' value is 'greater than or equal' to the arrival input and 'less than' the 'check-out' value, but it should also get all the documents in which the 'check-out' value is 'greater than' the the arrival input
And i dont know how to the $or clase in the query for the 'check-out' case
My Query:
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$arrival"
            }
          },
          new Date("2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z")
        ]
      },
      {
        $lt: [
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$arrival"
            }
          },
          new Date("2024-06-16T06:00:00.000Z")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})

Mongo playground Link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/1HRTg2eLeDa

You should never store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper Date objects. It will make your query much simpler.

Put the $or as a parent of the current $and, with the second part of the or being 'check-out' value is 'greater than' the the arrival input. Something like { $expr: { $or: [{$and: [...as above]}, {$gt: [checkout, input_arrival] }] } }

@WernfriedDomscheit If the values ​​in my collection were of type Date, how should my query change?

Finally manage to complete the query, thanks to the anwsers of everyone i manager to come up with the solution, this is how the query ended op like:
db.collection.find({
$expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$arrival"
                }
              },
              new Date("2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z")
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$arrival"
                }
              },
              new Date("2024-06-16T06:00:00.000Z")
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$checkout"
                }
              },
              new Date("2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z")
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$checkout"
                }
              },
              new Date("2024-06-16T06:00:00.000Z")
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})


If you store values as Date objects and if I understand you requirements correctly, it would be this one:
db.collection.find({
   $or: [
      { arrival: { $gte: new Date("2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z"), $lt: new Date("2024-06-16T06:00:00Z") } },
      { "check-out": { $gte: new Date("2024-06-11T06:00:00.000Z"), $lt: new Date("2024-06-16T06:00:00Z") } },
   ]
})

The $and operator is not needed.
